# Content script pattern "*://mail.google.com/*" doesn't match gmail when using firefox

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension that I've written for chrome. I recently decided I wanted to port it over to firefox, and I was surprised on how many things worked out of the box with no changes at all. However, one thing that has tripped me up is that for some reason my `gmail.js` content script is not being loaded. This is my content script:

```
{
  "name": "Copy Machine",
  "description": "Copies text more better",
  "version": "0.6",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon_16.png",
    "32": "icon_32.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
              "*://mail.google.com/*"
          ],
          "js": ["gmail.js"],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
        },
        {
          "matches": [
              "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": ["generic.js"],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ]
}
```

The first line of my gmail.js content script is:
`console.log("GMAIL SCRIPT IS RUNNING");`

And the first line of my generic.js content script is:
`console.log("GENERIC SCRIPT IS RUNNING");`

When I open my gmail account in firefox, in the console I see "GENERIC SCRIPT IS RUNNING", but not "GMAIL SCRIPT IS RUNNING."

With google chrome, this works as I would expect, but for some reason the URL pattern isn't matching. Is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Firefox. See if the content script is present in devtools (you'll need to enable chrome/addon debugging option though).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding `"*://mail.google.com/*"` to the `permissions` in the manifest file, and that got things working the way I expected. I then had to fix a few other bugs with apis that were not available, this is what I should have started with:

https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/porting-a-google-chrome-extension/

I then went back to file a bug report, and when I remove `"*://mail.google.com/*"` it's continues to work. So maybe there's some weird circular dependency thing going on? I'm not sure.